# results of fscanf are always 0.

Tags: file-io, scanf, c89

**I seem to be having trouble reading from the file data.txt.  Random numbers are being generated depending on the n that it is given however when I check the data with fscanf it returns 0's for both times in the code that I check**
`

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define DATA_FILE "data.txt"
#define OUT_FILE "output.txt"

void write_data(FILE *data, int n); 
int main(void)
{
int n, i, element;  
FILE *dataf = fopen(DATA_FILE, "w+"); 
      if (dataf == NULL)
         {
          printf("Can't open %s\n", DATA_FILE); 
          exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
         }
printf("Enter the amount of data entries: --> "); 
scanf("%d", &n); 
write_data(dataf, n); 

for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{ fscanf(dataf, "%d", &element); //first attempt to read the file
  printf("%d\n", element); 
} 
fclose(dataf); 
return 0; 
}
void write_data(FILE *data, int n)
{
  int i, element;  
  srand(time(NULL)); 
  for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
      {
       int r = rand() % (9 + 1 - 0) + 0;
       fprintf(data, "%d", r);
       fscanf(data, "%d\n", &element); //second attempt to read the file 
       printf("%d\n", element);  
      }
}
```

`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have a few problems here.  First, you opened the file for write access, but are trying to read it as well... I believe you need to fopen with "rw+" instead; If you had checked the return value of the fscanf's, as you did with fopen, this would have been apparent.  Secondly, rand() returns a FP value from zero to just less than one... which means r will always be zero.  Perhaps you meant to use multiplication (*) instead of modulo (%)L "int r = rand() * (9 + 1 - 0) + 0;" (or the simpler "int r = rand() * 10;"? And finally, even with the file opened for "rw+", following your fprintf the file pointer is positioned after the last value written, so your fscanf (both of them) would fail because there is nothing to read there.  To do what you are attempting, you would have to use fseek to backup over the value just written.  Again, this would have been apparent if you had checked the error status of your fscanf calls.
Hopefully this was helpful!